# Missing phpStorm project folder icons on OSX 10.10 in phpStorm explorer

Tags: macos, icons, phpstorm, finder

I am working with the deployment feature to easily upload files to a server. So opening a specific project folder for which I have already set up deployment gives me the opportunity to work with the project files instantly and also upload them without any problems.

The problem is with opening the right folder. When setting up deployment for a project you choose a folder as the 'root' folder for this one project and when one wants to load this settings he has to choose the right folder when opening a project. Sometimes there are some differences which folder is chosen as root (most of the time the folder is 'domain', but sometimes it's another folder).

When I now want open a project folder to work with the files and have the deployment ready, I can not recognize in the popped up window which folder is the right one. Friends of mine (win8/Linux) tell me that they have a phpStorm icon instead of the standard folder icon.

[image: opening a project folder in phpStorm]

On the other hand I told OSX to show me the hidden files on my system which results in following:

[image: finder showing .idea]

As you can see Finder shows me the .idea file, so at least I know the folder I am at right now is the project folder. But I in the future I don't want to check first in Finder, which folder the right one is and then open phpStorm to open it there.

I hope anybody understands my problem :). Thanks for any tips, really annoying topic.

Update:
Maybe the problem comes with the fact that phpStorm on OSX uses Finder as the explorer when trying to open a project folder. The explorer on Windows looks similar

Answer (score 0):

I posted on the jetbrains helpforum, the 'answer' was:
Relates to: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-100279
Duplicates: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-131303

Nothing anybody could have find out themselves, there does not seem to be a better answer than "give the folders related to PHPStorm the right icon, manually".